# How can I align text to baseline in EDC?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have two different font-sized texts in EDC, and I want them to be baseline-aligned:

[image]

This is the source generating this:

```
 text { "elm.text";
    scale: 1;   
    desc { "default";
       color: 255 0 0 255;
       text {
          text: "0.2";
          size: 32;
          ellipsis: -1;
          min: 1 1;
          max: 1 1;
          align: 1 1;
       }
    }
 }
 text { "elm.text.unit";
    scale: 1;
    desc { "default";
       color: 255 0 0 255;
       rel1 {
          to: "elm.text";
          relative: 1 0;
       }
       rel2 {
          to_y: "elm.text";
          relative: 1 1;
       }
       text {
          text: "amps";
          size: 16;
          align: 0 1;
       }
    }
 }
```

So, goal is something like this:

[image]

How can I do this with EDC?

Comment: Would let us know your profile - Mobile / TV / Wearable / IoT?

Comment: It's for wearable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no baseline align api in efl.

I think the easiest way is to set a suitable value for text align in `"elm.text.unit"`.

```
 text { "elm.text.unit";
    scale: 1;
    desc { "default";
       color: 255 0 0 255;
       rel1 {
          to: "elm.text";
          relative: 1 0;
       }
       rel2 {
          to_y: "elm.text";
          relative: 1 1;
       }
       text {
          text: "amps";
          size: 16;
          align: 0 0.75;
       }
    }
 }
```

[align 0.75](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC0Hw.png)

But if you want precise baseline align, you can use markup.
Since the `TEXT` part does not support markup, you should use the `TEXTBLOCK` part.

However, this method requires handling strings in app.
So I think the first method is better.

```
   group { "main";
      styles {
         style {
            name: "tb_style";
            base: "font=Tizen";
         }
      }
      parts {         
         textblock { "elm.text";
            scale;
            desc { "default";
               text {
                  style: "tb_style";
                  text: "<font_size=32 color=#FF0000>0.2</font_size><font_size=16 color=#FF0000>amps</font_size>";
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

[markup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Klc2e.png)